# Is it natural to use the phrasal verb "fasten up" in the sense of fastening one's belt in a car?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Would a native English speaker use *fasten up* in the sense of fastening one's belt in a car? For example:

> You had better **fasten up** as you never know what might happen on the road.

If it sounds off, what would a native English speaker say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very natural, if not the most one. So yes, a native English speaker would most likely use *fasten up* in that sense.

Also, as pointed out by @stevekeiretsu, *buckle up* is sometimes also used. One example that comes to my mind is from South Park, where Caitlyn Jenner says to President Trump

> *Buckle up, Buckaroo!

Side note: *Buckaroo* is an American slang for *cowboy*, mostly used during the 1950s.

Comment: "Buckle up" is another term I've heard, but yes, I agree, "fasten up" is natural.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu true, true! You reminded me of "buckle up"... I'll add to this the post with due credit, thank you!

Comment: The British Government used the now-discredited media start Jimmy Saville in a series of TV ads encouraging safety belt use with the slogan 'Clunk-click every trip".

Comment: As an American English speaker, "fasten up" in this context would be understandable but would show the speaker isn't a native AmE speaker.

Answer (score 4):

In the US, fasten up is understandable, though it's much more common to hear "fasten your seatbelt" without the preposition.

The most common phrasal verb for this is **[buckle up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buckle%20up)**, which is defined as "to fasten one's seatbelt."

"Buckle Up" has a long history in public service announcements and ad campaigns about road safety. See these linked examples: [Buckle Up for Life](https://www.buckleupforlife.org/riding-safely/driver-tips/), [Safe Kids Buckle Up](https://www.safekids.org/buckle) and [Risky Driving--The Benefits of Buckling Up](https://www.nhtsa.gov/risky-driving/seat-belts).